# Attach image file to email form via PHP email

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

```
<form>
<script>
var itemsAdded = Array();

function moveNumbers(text) { 
var i = itemsAdded.indexOf(text)
if ( i >= 0) { 
   itemsAdded.splice(i,1); 
} else {
   itemsAdded.push(text);
}
document.getElementById("result").value=itemsAdded.join(" "); 
 } 

 $(function() {
 for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
 console.log(i);
 $("body").append("<input type='checkbox' name='add' value='" + i + "'   onclick='moveNumbers(this.value)'/> Checkbox" + i + "<br/>");
 }
 });

</script>
<input type="text" name="filename" id="result" style="width:800px;">

<tr>

<?php
$path = "photos/";
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
echo "<table height='auto'width='auto'align='center'border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

if($file == "index.php")
continue;
if($file == ".")
continue;
if($file == "..")
continue;
{
echo ($x % 8 == 0) ? "</tr><tr>" : "";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='add' value='$file'    onclick='moveNumbers(this.value)'>
<img src='photos/$file'alt='$file' align='center' style='height:auto;width:140px;'>
<br>
$file
</td>";
$x++;
}
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
closedir($dir_handle);
?>

</form>
```

Script above opens a directory containing image files and displays them  with check boxes next to them. When a check box is checked it adds the file name into the text box. The next step which I have already setup is to add the text box input into an email form on another page, and user adds other details like name etc.

Is it possible when that check box is checked it could also add the file selected via file name and attach it to the email form via PHP email? Or would I need a data base type set up?

Comment: rather than showing a alarge amount of code if you could find the specific piece of code you are having difficulty with it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: I'm not here to study your very large piece of code that is unformatted and I have not clear sense of what it is you are trying to do, you need to be clearere about your problem.  Do you simply need to attache it as an attachment to an email?  Why would you require a db for this? Do you need another page?

Comment: I'm just trying to find out if you are able to attach the file selected via check box to another page containing the email form. As for the db part it is just a question asking do or don't I.

Comment: In that case you would need to save the file you have uploaded to disk (maybe a temporary directory example.com/mysite/files )and then on your email form page read show the files available to be attached to your email form.  You don't need to use a database, but if you have lots of users or its goign to be busy it might be easier to use a db.  Get it working just by savign to filesystem first.

Comment: Checkout a link like this to give you info on how to upload files http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: OK Cheers, I'll have a look the temp dir setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take any file that you upload and save it to disk thereby making it available to any other form you might have on your website.

See http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php for a tutorial on how to setup your php to upload a file.

1. Create Form
2. Upload file and save to disk on your server.
3. Create your email form
4. Read from disk the file you want to attach.

Use Swiftmailer http://swiftmailer.org/ to create your email and attach files from php.